# get dirname and invoke result in another command in unix

Tags: tcsh

I run this script in tcsh: 
goal: return name of current dir

```
set dir_name = basename $PWD | tr -d '\n'

git reset --hard $dir_name
```

But I got error in first line.

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I was wonder who was still using tcsh! :)

```
set dir_name = `basename "$PWD" | tr -d '\n'`
git reset --hard "$dir_name"
```

though, I don't think that "| tr -d '\n'" is required. Use the double quotes so you aren't hosed if your current directory name has a space in it.

Same thing in sh or bash, which if you are writing scripts, I recommend you use:

```
dir_name="$(basename "$PWD")"
git reset --hard "$dirname"
```

and if you don't need to reuse dir_name:

```
git reset --hard "$(basename "$PWD")"
```

Comment: What does `echo "dirname: $dir_name   PWD: $PWD"` return?
Also, which command gives the error?